# Use spec() to retrieve the full column specification for this data

Tags: r, r-markdown

Using Rmarkdown and trying to insert my data.

this is the code chunk I used:

````
```{r echo=TRUE, message=TRUE }

library(tidyverse)
congress<-read_csv("womenincongress.csv")

```
````

It gives me this

```
New names:
 -> ...1
Rows: 49 Columns: 5
-- Column specification -------------
Delimiter: ","
chr (1): state
dbl (4): ...1, senators, represen...

i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
```

I'm assuming I want all my data to be shown, but I'm not sure how to use the spec function.

Comment: have you tried ignoring this message, and just printing `congress` to the console?

Comment: Check the csv file. It is most likley there is a column with data but not a heading; `read_csv` automatically creates new names for variables with data but no name. You could use the `col_names` argument to provide your own names.

Comment: Assuming you have the `readr` package open type `?spec` in the console to retrieve the help documentation: "spec() extracts the full column specification from a tibble created by readr." So in your example type in `spec(congress)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example use of `spec()` to get full column specifications:

```
library(readr)

# write data to a temporary file for the purposes of demonstration 
f <- file.path(tempdir(), "iris10.csv")
write.csv(iris[1:10, ], f, row.names = FALSE)

# Read data using, set show_col_types to FALSE to suppress messages
df <- read_csv(f, show_col_types = FALSE)

# You can see how each column's type is converted 
spec(df)
#> cols(
#>   Sepal.Length = col_double(),
#>   Sepal.Width = col_double(),
#>   Petal.Length = col_double(),
#>   Petal.Width = col_double(),
#>   Species = col_character()
#> )
```